# Python 3.4: creating an asterisk diamond

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

so I've been trying to create a program where you prompt the user for the number of rows, and then the program prints out a diamond with input number of rows.

This is what the program is supposed to do:[(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjT3J.png)

This is what my code looks like

```
def main():
    ROWS = get_input()
    draw_pattern(ROWS)

def get_input():
    return int(input("Enter the number of rows (or -1 or -99 to quit): "))

def draw_pattern(ROWS):
    if ROWS == -1 or ROWS == -99:
        quit
    else:
        for x in range(0,(int)((ROWS/2)+1),1):          
            print ((int)((ROWS/2)-(2*x+1)/2)*" " + (2*x+1) * '*')

            for t in range((int)(x),0,-1):
                print((int)((ROWS/2)-(2*t-1)/2)*" " + (2*t-1) * '*')

main()
```

This is what it ends up doing:

```
Enter the number of rows (or -1 or -99 to quit): 7
   *
  ***
   *
 *****
  ***
   *
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
```

So what am I doing wrong? I assume it's something in my for loop that makes the rows not line up correctly. Can anyone give me a little help? Thanks.

Comment: You have a indentation problem, your second `for` loop is incorrectly indented. And what is `quit`?

Comment: Okay, I'll check the indentation. Quit is if you enter -1 or  -99 when it prompts you for the number of rows, it'll stop the program.

And the code runs, but not in the diamond pattern that I want it to run in, and I don't know why. I am on windows 7.

Comment: it should be `quit()`

Comment: You need to call it `quit()`. However, quit() is usually for the interactive interpreter and it is more normal to use `sys.exit()` for programs.

Comment: The indentation will mostly fix it, but it still doesn't look right for even numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work like this. (< 3 mins) (DO NOT use even numbers its going to look odd)

```
def main():
    ROWS = get_input()
    draw_pattern(ROWS)

def get_input():
    return int(input("Enter the number of rows (or -1 or -99 to quit): "))

def draw_pattern(ROWS):
    if ROWS == -1 or ROWS == -99:
        return

    else:
        for x in range(1, ROWS, 2):
            print(' ' * int(ROWS / 2.0 - x / 2.0) + ("*" * x))

        for x in range(ROWS, 1, -2):
            print(' ' * int(ROWS / 2.0 - x / 2.0) + ("*" * x))

        if x != 1:
            print(' ' * int(ROWS / 2.0 - 1 / 2.0) + ("*" * 1))

main()
```

Comment: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: Do you try this in python 3? Your unnecessary additional if clause raises a TypeError.

Comment: I didnt. Give me a sec

Comment: Ok. Its py3 compatible now.

Comment: This one also looks funny for even numbers, not sure what the desired output is.

Comment: @JoshuaGrigonis You cant align it one space on top with two at the bottom. These are characters not graphics.

Comment: I agree, but you could do 2 lines in the middle with the same width. e.g. 1, 3, 5, 5, 3, 1 for 6 ROWS. But apparently the asker is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, you can generate all the strings then print them out using formatting to center the diamond, e.g.:

```
>>> row = 5
>>> d = ('*' * (n if n <= row else 2*row-n) for n in range(1, 2*row, 2))
>>> for i in d:
...     print('{:^{w}}'.format(i, w=row))
  *  
 *** 
*****
 *** 
  *
```

For `row = 4`:

```
 *  
*** 
*** 
 *
```

Answer (score 0):

Points for obfuscation?

```
star = lambda rows:'\n'.join(('*'*(2*(i if i<rows//2 else rows-i-1)+1)).center(rows) for i in range(rows))
```

Odd

```
print(star(5))

  *  
 *** 
*****
 *** 
  *
```

Even

```
print(star(4))

  *  
 *** 
 *** 
  *
```